# How to access multidimensional dictionary on Django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I am trying to access a multidimensional dictionary in a Django template. I am able to view first level keys, but since second level keys I cannot see anything. In example dictionary is composed in this way:

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary[first_level] = {}
dictionary[first_level][second_level] = {}
...

and so on
```

From Django template I use:

```
{% for flk in dict %}
    <!-- Using nested for from the following, no output is shown -->
    {% for slk in dict.flk %}
        <th>First level key : {{ flk }} Second level key : {{ slk }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- -->
{% endfor %}
```

Have I to use a model or can I do it using this dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: This was only a python problem, not a django one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the solution on [this page](http://www.zedkep.com/blog/index.php?/archives/85-Iterating-over-a-dictionary-in-Django-templates.html)
Basically the code becomes

```
{% for flk, flv in dict.items %}
    {% for slk, slv in flv.items %}
        <th>First level key {{ flk }} Second level key {{ slk }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

where each dictionary is decomposed in keys `(flk, slk)` and values `(flv, slv)`.