# Django: multi-dimensional dictionary displayed in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following view and I'm finding it impossible to display through a template:

```
    sm = request.session.get('active_semester')

    semester_dates = SemesterDates.objects.filter(semester=sm)
    schedule = Schedule.objects.filter(semester=sm)
    student_enrolls = StudentEnroll.objects.filter(schedule__semester = sm).values_list('schedule__pk', 'student__family_member__first_name', 'student__family_member__last_name').order_by('student__family_member__last_name')
    schedule_array={}
    for a in schedule:
        schedule_array[a.id]={'course':a.course_catalog.course_name, 'students': [], 'teachers': []}

    for (pk, fname, lname) in student_enrolls:
        schedule_array[pk]['students'].append(fname + ' ' + lame)
```

This produces the following output. Note that there are two "Arduino" classes because they are held at different times. So, I'm using the Schedule.pk as the dictionary key to keep them separate. This way my class list is different for each instance of this course.

```
{2L: 
   {
    'students': [u'Jessica Ryan', u'Annie Ryan'], 
    'course': u'Arduino Programming', 
    'teachers': []
   }, 
4L: 
   {
    'students': [], 
    'course': u'Lego Animation 3rd-4th Grade', 
    'teachers': []
   }, 
5L: 
   {
    'students': [], 
    'course': u'Life skills - card games', 
    'teachers': []
   }, 
6L: 
   {
    'students': [], 
    'course': u'test', 
    'teachers': []
   }, 
7L: {
    'students': [u'Mark Ryan'], 
    'course': u'Arduino Programming', 
    'teachers': []
    }
}
```

In my template, I have the following. This is not working but gives you a glimpse of what I'm trying to do.

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
    {% for e in schedule %}
        <tr class="info">
          <td><h3>{{ e.course_catalog }}</h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            {% for key in schedule_array.items|lookup:0 %}
              <h5>Dict Key: {{ key }} & Value: {{ value }}  {{e.pk}} </h5>
              {% for k2 in key.items %}
                k2: {{k2}} Students: {{k2.students}}<br>
                {% for k3 in k2 %}
                    {% for s in k3 %}
                      k3:{{s.students}}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
              endfor 2
              {% endfor %}
            endfor 1
            {% endfor %}
          </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through my schedule object. Then, I'd like to look up the primary key (e.pk) in the schedule_array dictionary. From that, I'd like to loop through the list of students and then do it again with the teachers.  I'm not able to get this to work. Regardless of what I try. I know I'm doing it wrong but can't find the correct way to accomplish it.

Comment: You can try this code i found, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860787/3027579

Comment: I had tried that but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  {% for key, value in schedule_array.items %}
    <tr class="info">
      <td><h3>{{ value.course }}</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        {% for s in value.students %}
            k2: {{s}}
          {% endfor %}
      </td>
      <td>
        {% for t in value.teachers %}
            k2: {{t}}
          {% endfor %}
      </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```