# Looping Multi-Dimensional Array in Django HTML Template

Tags: python, django

My Dictionary looks like below

```
 Table:
     0:
         Name1 : ABC
         Name2 : IJK
     1: 
         Name1 : QQQ
         Name2 : FFF
     2:  
         Name1 : WWW
         Name2 : RRR
```

Currently the below HTML code working with hard coded '0', but nor working with 'row'

Here **key** = ****'Table'****, as mentioned above.

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {% for row in value %}
    <br> {{value.0.Name1}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

for : **{{value.0.Name1}}** --> Gives output as **ABC**

In the above code, if i replace **'0'** with **'row'** then i get error.

Please help.

Best Regards,
Namratha Patil

Comment: Here's a similar question and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065088/django-multi-dimensional-dictionary-displayed-in-template

Comment: @EdKohler Thank you Kohler, followed exactly and GOT IT. Have Fun.